Decreasing sequence with sum equals 1
Problem
For $n\in\mathbb{N}\,$, $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$ are the real numbers and satisfy

$a_1\ge a_2\ge\cdots\ge a_n\ge0$
$\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k=1$

Prove that $\frac{l}{n}\le\sum_{k=1}^{l}a_k\le1$ for all $l$ s.t. $1\le l\le n\,$.
Question
By 1. , we get $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k=1\ge\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_n=na_n\,$.
It follows that $a_n\le\frac{1}{n}\,$.
Let $A$ be the set $A=\left\{(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)\mid a_1\ge a_2\ge\cdots\ge a_n\ge0, \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k=1\right\}$ and let $p$ be the maximum value of $k\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $a_k\ge\frac{1}{n}, a_{k+1}<\frac{1}{n}\,$.
We get $p$ is the function that $p : A\to \{1, 2, \cdots, n\}\,$.
Therefore, we have $\sum_{k=1}^{l}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{l}{n}\le\sum_{k=1}^{l}a_k\le \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k=1$ for $l\in\{1, 2, \cdots, n\}\,$.
Could I ask if the description that $p$ is the function and $l$ can correspond to the output of the function $p$ is correct?

From https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info: "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

Martin, I really appreciate you informing me. I will make the correction right away.

Note that $\sum_{k=1}^l a_k \ge a_1$

In the proof, the sentence "We get that ..." is not clear. You didn't prove anything.

Gribouillis, I am not sure how to describe the fact that each element of $A$ corresponds to one of the values in ${1, 2, \cdots, n}$ when proving that p is a function.

FYI A proof by contradiction is much easier, and flows almost immediately. Show that if $ \sum_{k=1}^l a_k < l/n$, then 1/ $ a_l < 1/n$ and 2/ $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k < 1$.

Calvin, I am already familiar with the solution using proof by contradiction, and I initially approached the problem in this manner as well. However, I later recalled a solution using the function $p,$.

Denote $a_n=u_n, \ a_{n-1}=u_n+u_{n-1},\ldots, a_1=u_n+\cdots +u_1.$ Then
$$1=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{i=k}^nu_i=\sum_{i=1}^nu_i\sum_{k=1}^i1=\sum_{i=1}^niu_i.$$ Similarly $$\sum_{k=1}^{\ell}\sum_{i=k}^nu_i=\sum_{i=1}^n iu_i\times \frac{\min(i,\ell)}{i}=\sum_{i=1}^n iu_i\times\min\left(1,\frac{\ell}{i}\right)\geq \frac{\ell}{n}.$$
